# What is the approach for list / stream / download files from cloud?

Tags: android, web-services, rest, cloud, audio-streaming

On an Android device, I'm trying to list down mp3 file names (list view) , stream/buffer a mp3 file , download the mp3 file available in the cloud.

I was thinking about couple of approaches that I can follow to get this done

1. Host mp3 files on a server, & probably create a web service which gives me the above functionality and at the client side, I should be consuming the web service. ( Single server for both Web service & hosting mp3 files ).
2. Host Mp3 files on a server1, Deploy a web service on server2, this way I can easily structure and manage mp3 files.

What is the usual approach that app's like Google Play Music, Saavn ... follow ? If there is any other solutions I can look into, please suggest them.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the amount of space your data will occupy, the bandwidth available on your server infrastructure, the kind of speed you need, how fault tolerant you want it to be, the budget you have etc and many more factors.

Generally, I'd suggest you use a single server to host your data and application logic in the beginning. If/when you start getting more users for your service, then you can start thinking about scaling up using a more distributed architecture (like maybe firing up a couple of instances of Amazon S3) etc.

Your client mobile app should be implemented in a way that it doesn't need to know what kind of backend architecture is supporting it so that you can easily change the architecture later without affecting the client side code. Look into RESTful web services for this.